# HTTPs on GCP Compute Engine Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, https, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using a jenkins in GCP Compute Engine and I need to make it use HTTPS.

I've tried this solution, to force jenkins to run with https but it didnt work: https://jansipke.nl/enable-https-jenkins/

Do you know some way to make Compute Engine to run only with HTTPs or if google has any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to [configure HTTPS/SSL on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#https-and-ssl):

- Setting up the Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance to terminate
  HTTPS.
- [Configuring HTTPS load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http).

Note that **HTTPS load balancing on GCP makes use of instance groups**, so it's important to understand [how instance groups work](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups) before setting this up.
The HTTPS/SSL configuration steps (registering a domain, configuring DNS, getting an SSL cert) are the same that one would normally do on a non-cloud server.

You can also [set up port forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#port-forwarding-over-ssh) or a [SOCKS proxy](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely#socks-proxy-over-ssh) as an alternative security method for a GCE instance.